# Jquery autocomplete ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I've browsed through the questions but I didn't find anything that helped me to make it work.

it enters in ajax.
someone told me to disable those two strings:

```
//contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
//dataType: "json",
```

but it doesn't work anyway.

I get this: cannot read property length of undefined, and if I use datatype I get an another error.
It seems there's something wrong into the jquery-1.10.2.js file

```
$("#MainContent_TxtCitta").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/CodiceFiscale/CaricaTextBox",                        
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",

            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            data: "{ 'Citta': '" + request.term + "' }",

            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {

                    return {

                        value: item.Citta
                    }
                }))

            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
```

(I've tried with jquery-1.11.1.js, same problem)

Comment: Assuming you're using jQuery AutoComplete here is an example in the doc http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I checked it some days ago, I can't adapt it to my project.
There are too many differences, and he makes things in a different way. Thanks for the link